# MySQL Can't insert value after creating new column

Tags: mysql

**FIRST QUERY :**

```
ALTER TABLE my_world ADD my_field TEXT; #Adding new column `my_field` in `my_world` table
```

**SECOND QUERY :**

```
INSERT INTO my_world(my_field) VALUES('Hello world'); #Inserting value `Hello world` in `my_field` column
```

After executing the abobe queries, MySQL show `1 row affected.` But the table is look like -

**OUTPUT**

```
+---------------+---------------+
| id            | my_field      |
+---------------+---------------+
|  1            |  NULL         |
|  2            |  NULL         |
|  3            |  NULL         |
+---------------+---------------+
```

> **Note** : `id` is primary key with Auto Increment

Why `my_field` always inserting `NULL` value instead of `Hello world`?

What is the solution of this problem?

Comment: Is this the real table name/column name which you are using right now. Because, nothing wrong in query.

Comment: my_field is the `text` Datatype? If `text` then check length. Your query is right.

Comment: please provide export of the table structure after adding the new column.

Comment: `TEXT` datatype length is by default `65,535 bytes ~64kb`. So there is no problem. @RamaLingam

Comment: There is no problem in table structure. Thank you for asking. I solved the inserting problem!  @krasipenkov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I solved my problem by adding SQL `UPDATE` after my "First Query"**

**QUERY :**

```
ALTER TABLE my_world ADD my_field TEXT;
UPDATE my_world SET my_field='';

INSERT INTO my_world(my_field) VALUES('Hello world');
INSERT INTO my_world(my_field) VALUES('Good By world');
#More insert query is here............................
```

> Now it is inserting new rows with VALUES in my new column.

**OUTPUT :**

```
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| id            | my_field      | Other_fields ..... |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
|  1            |  Hello world  | .................. |
|  2            |  Good By world| .................. |
|  .....        |  .....        | .................. |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

> But still wondering why need to execute `UPDATE my_world SET my_field='';` query.

Answer (score -1):

Try `INSERT INTO my_world.my_field VALUES ('Hello world');` without braces and the dot.

Comment: `my_field` is a column not a table so I don't think this would work

Comment: Ahh No! I have other fields to insert. Like `name`,`email` etc at a time. @bassxzero

Comment: So, all values entering except `my_field`. Correct @SumonSarker ?

Comment: Like as `INSERT INTO my_world(email,name,my_field) VALUES('email@email.com','My name','Hello World')` @nana-partykar